# Redirect Folder and Contents to New Site

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

A WordPress site with a shopping cart plugin is being deactivated and the products are moving to a new site. I'm trying to redirect (301) all references to products at the WP site to the new site. I've tried a variety of things including examples I found here with no success.

I started with this in the .htaccess file at the WP site *before* the WP rules:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^product/(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/products/
```

I also tried it as a rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^product/(.*) http://www.newsite.com/products/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I don't care which product is being referenced. I just want to send all such references to the main products page at the new site.

I'm pretty lightweight regarding htaccess, having mostly used it for very simple things. And my regular expressions might be off as well. I'm out of my depth for this one. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Both rules should work, just make sure it is first rule.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out they do work; I was uploading the revised version of .htaccess to the wrong version of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring my stupidity for not getting the .htaccess file uploaded to the right place, eventually this rule worked:

```
RedirectMatch 301 product/.* http://www.newsite.com/products/
```